# Browser support as of May 2021 of event.target.id

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I checked at https://www.caniuse.com but I do not think it's the right place (it's more about CSS and HTML from what I understood).

I am basically listening on an "animationend" event, and I want to know the ID of the element that triggered the event, to hide it:

```
  var element = document.getElementById("animconfetti");
  element.addEventListener("animationend", listener, false);
  function listener(event) {
    var id = event.target.id
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'
  }
```

It works on MY setup (mostly Firefox), but I do not really have access to Safari Mobile, Opera, Safari on MacOs, Chrome Mobile, Samsung Browser... So, I would like to know how "safe" and "compatible" this command is.

Thank you

Comment: The [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will be whatever element triggered the event, and if it has an [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id), `event.target.id` will exist. I wouldn’t know of a browser where this basic mechanism didn’t work.

Comment: To add not only will id be available, but style will be too.  So the getElementById is not doing you anything here.

Comment: @Keith I don't understand what you mean. The code works. Do you mean I can do something like event.target.id.style.display='none'?

Comment: NO, I mean you can do it like `event.target.style.display='none'`